# No output signal with ULN2803 on Proteus

Tags: arduino, voltage, amplifier, proteus, uln2803

I'm using an ULN2803 to amplify a voltage signal from an Arduino, but the output is 0 V even though the input is 5 V. I've tried multiple simple circuits to test it, but it just doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it's a Proteus problem or something else.

PS: I need to get the 5 V to 10 V, controlling it from an MCP4728, maybe you can suggest other amplifiers.

[image]

Comment: Is COM grounded? Also why 10k in series, that's very low current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ULN2803](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf?ts=1653836570193&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FULN2803A) is an open-collector output like this: -

[image]

In other words it doesn't magically generate a voltage from nothing; you have to add a power supply of the correct voltage in the output circuit in series with your load such as like this: -

[image]

Notice the 12 volt power source feeding all the LED circuits. Circuit image from [here](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/uln2803-with-led-with-12v-vcc.371075/).